# Использование обученной модели в python

Tags: python, cv2

Обучил модель на сайте 'roboflow', на выходе получил файл с обученной моделью - best.pt .

Я хочу обнаруживать на экране своего компьютера объекты, по которым училась нейросеть и получать их координаты.

Как мне реализовать это?

Что у меня есть сейчас (захватываю только часть экрана):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui


sct = mss()

while True:
    x,y = pyautogui.position()
    bounding_box = {'top': y - 100, 'left': x - 100, 'width': 200, 'height': 200}
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(sct_img))

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Ну там на сайте должен быть пример кода, как готовую модель подключать. Нет никакого универсального способа и даже универсального формата для хранения моделей.